# Mock OAuth server for testing

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing

I'd like to know if it is possible to simulate the oAuth(1,2) authentication flow. I'd like to test without the need to connect to the provider itself. It should be possible as it is just some communication exchange. I'm not looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12521385/2944265) where they still communicate with remote server. I'd like to be completely offline, when testing.

Maybe I can run my own oAuth server. I should be using Google oAuth services so the server should behave same like they do. Does google provide some code for their oAuth server, or is it possible to create some fake server. Note the test should be more integration test. I would like to command the server to return some predefined responses. Switching to live oAuth providers will be just changing the remote URL.

Maybe just some http server is ok, I just need to care about the proper format of communicated messages.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Client Side REST Tests](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-client) section of Spring Reference docs. With this support you can easily fake the server and record desired behaviour into `MockRestServiceServer`.

[Here are some examples I created.](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/blob/master/04-rest/0404-rest-boot-client/src/test/java/net/lkrnac/book/eiws/chapter04/client/RestClientBootApplicationTest.java)

Comment: I guess it is really close. In the example you are quering the user data right? Is it posible to do the authentication. Lets say I want to test authenticate method. So I need the server to return some token, send the redirect address etc.

Answer (score 2):

Please see steps below to **mock OAuth2 token** to be used for faster local development using SOAPUI.

**Steps:**

1. Create a REST soapUI project, create a POST resource for URL "http://localhost:9045/oauth/token".
2. Create a Mock Service for above resource.
3. Create a Mock response as shown below, you can add your own parameters and values depending on your requirements.

   `{
   "access_token":"MockOauth2TokenForLocaldevelopmentnTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":35999,
   "scope":"read write",
   "jti":"4d540b94-1854-45fa-b1d6-c2039d94b681"
   }`
4. Start the mock service.
5. Test using your local REST POST request.

**Mock Response:**

[image]

**Mock Oauth2 SOAPUI testing:**

[image]

Comment: This is one part of the problem where we mock /token endpoint. I have a similar problem where I need to mock entire workflow using wiremock. I have three different api requests for auth, redirect url and token. But no luck. Do you have any idea how to simulate/mock the first two steps?